# Creating a "Filtered" Data Extension from Synchronized Data Extension in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, data-model

I have a synchronized data extension that I would like to create a new sendable data extension from but with only a select group of the records in the synchronized data extension.

I have a field in the synchronized data extension that I can use as a filter to do this. What would be the best way to go about doing this? Looked through the documentation and salesforce doesn't provide any clear guidance

Would we use automation studio, extract the information via csv and reupload to new data extension, audience builder/attribute groups, or is there another more straightforward way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this very easily in Automation Studio by creating a Data Filter activity and scheduling it to run on a time interval, eg. daily, hourly, etc.

Here’s all the steps:

**Create a Data Filter**

1. Log in to the Marketing Cloud application.
2. Go to Email Studio | Email | Subscribers | Data Filters. Click Create.
3. Select the Data Source from the picklist. Select the name of the Synchronized Data Extension to be used from the picklist.
4. Create the condition for the filter. Select attributes (or fields) by dragging them from the left-hand column onto the canvas. When your conditions are defined, click Save.
5. Enter a Name, External Key, and Description and, from the location section, pick a folder where you wish to save your filter.
6. Click Save.

**Create a Filter Activity**

1. Log in to the Marketing Cloud application.
2. Go to Journey Builder | Automation Studio | Activities.
3. Click Create Activity, then select Filter.
4. Click Next.
5. Enter a Name, External Key, and Description. Enter a Name, External Key, and Description and choose the folder where you would like the filter activity to be.
6. Click the Data Filters folder under the "Filter Definition" section and choose the Data Filter created during the "Create a Data Filter" process.
7. Click Next.
8. Enter a Name, an External Key, and a Description for the Data Extension you'd like to filter by and click Next, then click Finish.

**Add Filter Activity to an Automation**

1. Log in to the Marketing Cloud application.
2. Go to Journey Builder | Automation Studio | Activities.
3. Click New Automation.
4. Select Schedule or File Drop for the type of Automation (based on your preference) and drag it into the 'Starting Source' column on the right.
5. Enter a name into the 'Untitled Automation' field, then click Done.
6. Drag the Filter option from the "Activities" section where the text 'Drop Activity on to the canvas' is displayed.
7. Click Choose.
   8. Expand the Filter folder to display the filter that you created during the "Create a Filter Activity" process.
8. Select the Filter, then click Done.
   Note: After completing these steps, input any additional steps (for example, email). You can also input steps before the filter. Think of the Filter step to be the "Refresh" for your data extension.
9. Configure the schedule or file drop as necessary.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320525&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

Comment: I'm getting a no symbol whenever I try to click on the synchronized data extension and it doesn't show up in salesforce data extensions when attempting to create the data filter.

Comment: In that case, try it differently: Go to Subscribers > Synchronized Data Extensions and on the right hand side of the Synched DE name there should be a filter icon. Click on it and create your filter and filtered DE. Check if you can then use it in Automation Studio. As an altaernative and a solution that I always use, you can automate an SQL query to filter the data from Synched DEs and write it to a separate DE.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zuzannamj I was able to get it created, much appreciated!